# BigDecimal to String in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to convert a BigDecimal value to a string. I did as follows:

```
    @Column(name="CASE_ID", precision=22, scale=0)
public BigDecimal getCaseId() {
    return this.caseId;
}

public void setCaseId(BigDecimal caseId) {
    this.caseId = caseId;
}    String caseId = "";

caseId = vList.get(i).getCaseId().toString();
dataCell.setCellValue(caseId);
```

I get a runtime exception, as follows:

> 2013-03-11 14:49:11,046 WARN  [HTTPThreadGroup-4]
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor: Unhandled Exception thrown:
>   class java.lang.ClassCastException
>
> Wrapped exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at com.report.getExport(ExportToExcelAction.java:468)
    at com.report.getExport.view(ExportToExcelAction.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at gov.pbgc.spectrum.util.SpectrumLookupDispatchAction.execute(SpectrumLookupDispatchAction.java:119)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
```

I know `toString()` converts `BigDecimal` to `String`. I don't get a compile time exception, but I do get a runtime exception. Any insights?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer yet.  We don't know what `getCaseId()` is returning (supposedly a BigDecimal).

Comment: vList.get(i).getCaseId() is not returning what you expected.(big decimal)

Comment: There is no cast in the code fragment, add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: What `vList.get(i)` returns?

Comment: its an object(POJO class)

Comment: What is the name of that POJO class?

Comment: CsValidateReport.java

Answer (score 0):

OK..Then change your code in following way:

`caseId = ((CsValidateReport)vList.get(i)).getCaseId();` 
And instead of this line:

`String caseId = "";` use `String sCaseId = "";` And then you can proceed as follows:

```
caseId = ((CsValidateReport)vList.get(i)).getCaseId();
sCaseId = caseId.toPlainString() ;
dataCell.setCellValue(sCaseId );
```

Comment: `com.report.getExport(ExportToExcelAction.java:468)` . Have you checked the code written at this line? What is written at line 468 of "ExportToExcelAction.java" ?

Comment: caseId = ((CsValidateReport)vList.get(i)).getCaseId().toString();

Comment: @JNPW: `caseId` is the variable of `BigDecimal` ?

Comment: @JNPW: If `caseId` is the `BigDecimal` variable then use the updated code as I posted in my answer..